# How do I fetch an array from a smart contract using cacheCall()?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, drizzle

Let's say I have an array in my smartcontract that looks like this

```
string[] public employees;
```

I am able to fetch data from `employees` if I know the index, like this

```
contract.method["employees"].catchCall([i]); // i is the index
```

How am I supposed to get all items in `employees` if I don't know how many are there?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a solidity version above 0.6 the ABIEncoderV2 is no longer considered experimental. 
[Github Solidity 0.6 Release](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.0)

With the new Encoder you can return dynamic arrays and structs.

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


contract SomeContract {
    string[] public employees;

    function getAllEmployees() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return employees;
    }
}
```